# How can I add Https in my ionic cordova app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

The issue is simple, I need my app in android and ios have https in the domain. I mean, I want to change **http:**//localhost to **https:**//localhost o whatever domain with hhtps. I need it because I have to add into a white list my url and only admit https urls, so... How can I do that with Ionic and cordova apps?

The error: [error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trSjJ.png)

My app domain: [image]

The problem is that here in this list I cant add http url must be https or other[image]

Comment: Also if i get other domain like domain://newurl it also works

Comment: Sorry but you dont need anything like this .. you are not going to host your application on any sevrer like websites ,. it will be on the either playstore or apple store ..

Comment: `ionic serve` is just for you to develop things.. where it shows you your application with localhost URL

Comment: I get this error: Access to fetch at 'https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/v1/analytics/log?token=test_2ZVVQMH5KNDUHEEJ6HRL26HXPM3DNDYH' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: I need change my url for another, is this possible to ionic apps?

Comment: can you show me a screenshot where it shows you localhost

Comment: I add u some screenshot in main post, any ideas?

Comment: It should not be an issue .. since it's for application purpose only.. it won't effect anything in your application .. you can use it the way it is .. if u have any specific issue related to this please specify

Comment: What the exactly the reason behind this change

Comment: Google that in cordova , there is an attribute u can put in config.xml but i think its for android and u can do another thing also for ios to make url https..